# Android: Download Returned Zip file from URL

Tags: android, url, zip, webserver, download

If I have a URL that, when submitted in a web browser, pops up a dialog box to save a zip file...how would I go about catching and downloading this zip file in android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void downloadFromUrl(String url, String outputFileName) {


    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/");
    if (dir.exists() == false) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    try {
        URL downloadUrl = new URL(url); // you can write any link here

        File file = new File(dir, outputFileName);          
        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = downloadUrl.openConnection();

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);          
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();




    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }



}
```

Comment: That works as a charm...
For sometimes it may throw "networkOnMainThreadException". In that case do this process in AsnycTask and it would be fine.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) to download the Url, though I am not sure if there are any redirects, DownloadManager will take care of it.

Comment: Wow I don't understand your Awesome example with yours connections and managements and yours inputstreams... I read documentation .... but I don't know how I can put "public static final String COLUMN_REASON" mmm... (irony)